# MSBuild integration error

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to build the solution with MSBuild. For that I've place the dirs.proj file at solution level and ran "build -c" command. But every time I'm getting below error.

1>MSBuild.cmd "c:\enlistments\src\meap\cache - copy\dirs.proj" /nologo /p:BuildingInSeparatePasses=true /p:BuildingWithBuildExe=true /clp:NoSummary /verbosity:normal  /clp:ShowCommandline /m:4 /nr:false  /Target:WriteToAssemblyIdentityLog /p:MSBuildCleaning=true failed - rc = 0x000000ff

Please help me out...

Regards,
Dinesh

The DIRS.proj file is like below The DIRS.proj file is like below.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.5" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Import Project="$(EnvironmentConfig)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectFiles Include="Cache - Copy\AzureCacheWrapper\AzureCacheWrapper.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(ExtendedTargetsPath)\Traversal.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: The DIRS.proj file is like below
The DIRS.proj file is like below.

<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(EnvironmentConfig)" />
 <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectFiles Include="Cache - Copy\AzureCacheWrapper\AzureCacheWrapper.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(ExtendedTargetsPath)\Traversal.targets" />
</Project>

Comment: What's the content of MSBuild.cmd?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a ";" after the '2003">'.  Is your xml in your proj file "well formed"?

That would be #1.  Make sure you xml is well formed.  Open it up in notepad++ and select "xml" as the language.  Or open it up in XmlNotePad 2007 (from Microsoft).  Or any other xml formatting tool.

BTW: You have 2 "Import Project" statements.  You have to show that xml as well if #1 doesn't fix your issue.